# Map column names to variable names in Codeigniter custom classes

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a custom class called User which contains 2 variables name and id and when i fetch the data from my database the returned column names are user_id and user_name,is there a way i could map user_id to id and user_name to name?
One way would be to loop through the result array and set it manually but is there any other way?

Snippets of code

```
class User
{
public $id;
public $name;
}
```

Data returned from mysql

```
"user_id": "2",
"user_name": "John Does"
```

Using

```
$query = $this->db->query("QUERY");
$rows = $query->custom_result_object('User');
```

I want to store user_id in id and user_name in name for my custom class User.
As pointed out i could use an alias in the mysql query but i would also like to add another functionality of converting the id returned from mysql to an integer,in my db its stored as an int but when the query results are returned its returned as a string and i want to cast it to an integer before sending the results to the front end.

Comment: Not completly clear what you mean without showing code.. but you can use a alias in the select like this `$this->db->select('user_id AS id, user_name AS name .....`. that maps user_id to id and user_name to name